# How do you switch string at the same fret after bending?

Tags: guitar, note-bending

Here is a demo of switching to the string above, but it could also be the string below, of course: https://goo.gl/photos/BSDJ7DcUygNi8veC7 I find this quite awkward to do.

The thing is the bended note should stay bended before the next note is picked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need to switch to the string above and you can't bend down and you need to hold the bend until you pick the next note - well that's clearly impossible so your only option is to learn to make the transition really quickly. Most awkward changes just require practice to make them sound as smooth as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your next note is on a lower (i.e., thicker) string (what you call "the string above"), then you could use the same finger that you use for bending. This is done by letting the lower string slip under your finger while you bend, which will allow you to fret that new string by just rolling your finger a little bit. This is done a lot in blues playing, but in that case the new string is already picked while it is still bent upwards. This will give you the effect of bending the higher (sounding) string, and then releasing the lower (sounding) string.

When the next note is on the higher (sounding) string (i.e., the thinner string), you would normally use another finger, namely one with a higher number (I'm talking about conventional fretting hand finger numbering). E.g., if you bend with your 3rd finger you would fret the next note with your 4th finger, if you bend with the 2nd finger you fret the next note with your 3rd finger, etc.

Comment: Hmm, got some noise when letting it slip.

Comment: Use a free finger to damp the released string?

Comment: I tried it out and it does work - but it needs some practice

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1:

You could also just play the same note on a **different string and fret** to avoid this problem? E.g. play the bend as you were playing it, but play the following note on the same (B) string by sliding back to the 6th fret. This would of course be a solution which is impossible if you would play the same riff on the 3rd fret for example.

Suggestion 2:

**Replace the bend** by a slide so the problem is discarded? I think, in practice, that this thing you are suggesting requires some dexterity and exercise if you want it to sound smoothly. Not impossible though, so if you really like the sound of this specific lick: keep practicing untill you master it!